# google app engine project: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request

Tags: google-app-engine

when I executed my web app engine project in java for login application it showed this error can any one help
I am using eclipse kepler java 1.7 in my system 
I am not getting any exception. enabled data store also.
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Comment: Check the GAE logs.  If you see this `Session support is not enabled in appengine-web.xml`, then open up appengine-web.xml and uncomment/add this line: `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>`

Answer (score 17):

The message indicates that there has been a problem while trying to startup your App and serve your request.

I suggest the following:

- Visit the Administration Console for your application. Check out the Logs and see if there is any message indicating the problem.
- Alternately, I also suggest that you look at your log4j.properties and configure the level to a lower level than is present for e.g. INFO or DEBUG. This might throw up more information around the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is good advice. In the current version of Google Developers Console, there is a menu entry called Monitoring, which has Logs and Alerts. The logs are very detailed.

Answer (score 3):

In my package.json file, for example I was missing node at front of main.js.

```
"start": "**node** main.js"
```

And it was throwing that error.

Answer (score 1):

in my case too i forget to change the start operation from :

```
"start": "nodemon server.js",
```

to:

```
"start": "node server.js",
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with deploying my web application. I had forgot to set a redirect uri for authentication

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate your answer a bit.